# how test scripts interact with oFono firmware

Tags: dbus, yocto

I need to use ofono in yocto project for modem testing. I have gone through the basics of ofono at https://01.org/ofono.
and we can use dbus to send ofono test scripts on command line.
But I couldn't find how ofono test scripts interact with ofono firmware using dbus ?

Please explain

Comment: Ofono does not have firmware, it's just a D-Bus service. If you want to see how the test scripts work,  just read them: They are plain python scripts.

Comment: Thanks jku, can we give a 'dbus' commands through command line or do we need to use some application ?